# jQuery: how to get the sub-menus of sub-menu?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a HTML menu that has parent menus, sub-menus and under each sub-menu, there could be other sub-menus etc etc...

Now, I need to add an icon (bars) to the parent menus & sub-menus that have sub-menus. and this icon adding process should also work the same for the submenus that have other submenus! I hope that makes sense.

Currently, using my code below, I can add the icon to the parent menus that have sub-menus but this doesn't seem to work for the sub-menus with submenus under them!

Every element has the same class name which is `.MyLi` so I don't understand why it only adds the icon to the parent menu but not the submenu.

This is my code in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/134836/

And this is the jQuery code that I use:

```
$('.MyLi:has(ul)').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html()+' <i style="position:absolute; top:0; right:20px;font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-bars mybars" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
 });
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question and requirement correctly, this might be what you attempt to do?

I have changed the style `position` and `left` to place the icon in front of the `<li>`. However, it would be better to add a class to the icon and control CSS in that class.

```js
$('.MyLi:has(ul)').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<i style="position:relative; top:0; left:0px;font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-bars mybars" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});
```

```css
.MyLi {
  color: grey;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="MyLi Home" data-cont="Home" id="2"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="MyLi Management Policies" data-cont="Management Policies" id="52"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Management Policies</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="MyLi Abuse" data-cont="Abuse" id="87"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Abuse</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Communication" data-cont="Communication" id="89"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Communication</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Confidentiality" data-cont="Confidentiality" id="97"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Confidentiality</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Food and Drink" data-cont="Food and Drink" id="95"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Food and Drink</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Health and Safety" data-cont="Health and Safety" id="91"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Health and Safety</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Moving and Handling" data-cont="Moving and Handling" id="93"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Moving and Handling</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Worksheet" data-cont="Worksheet" id="99"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Worksheet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="MyLi Mental Health" data-cont="Mental Health" id="54"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mental Health</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="MyLi Aggression and Abuse" data-cont="Aggression and Abuse" id="109"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aggression and Abuse</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Game" data-cont="Game" id="973"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Game</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Health Assessments" data-cont="Health Assessments" id="101"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Health Assessments</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Medications" data-cont="Medications" id="112"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Medications</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Mental Disorders" data-cont="Mental Disorders" id="105"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mental Disorders</a></li>
        <li class="MyLi Other Articles" data-cont="Other Articles" id="114"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Other Articles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="MyLi Quality Assurance" data-cont="Quality Assurance" id="47"><a><i></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quality Assurance</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```